# Retrieve values from a nested response in Postman

Tags: json, rest, api, object, postman

I am using postman to get certain responses. Below is my response.

[image]

Here I have some other api request links integrated with this response. Is there any possibility that I can get values inside these apis also. Its like retrieve values forom both parent api request and child api request.

I know this is possible using a java code. But is there any other exsiting software that I can use for this?

Comment: It's a bit confusing as to what you're trying to achieve. Is it like you want to call an endpoint that was returned as a part of the response? For eg: Calling the delete endpoint or the project endpoint?

Comment: You definitely can get the response and get those links but what is it that you're trying to achieve? Simply check for a link existence? or do you need to somehow use for chaining requests?

Comment: @SivcanSinghI need to call project endpoint

Comment: @socalcheesehead I need to get some other attributes from this project endpoint.

Comment: You ONLY need to get the info for the `project` key? For instance you're only interested in `project -> href -> /api/v3/time_entries/1`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would recommend combining multiple requests into a chain or even a [workflow](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows/). The idea is to have the first request fetch `href` endpoints that get called in subsequent requests. For that, the initial request needs a post-request test script that reads the `href` values from the [response](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference#pmresponse) and stores it in a [environment or global variable](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/).
Like so:

```
// persist project href for next request
pm.environment.set("projectUrlPath", pm.response.json().embedded.elements[0]._links.project.href);
```

Your next request in the line would than use this variable to build the request url. Like so:

```
http://www.example.com{{projectUrlPath}}
```

The key is to correctly navigate to the right attribute in the response json JavaScript object. This online tool might help you with that:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_json_parse